# Raspberry pi using bluetooth.discover_devices() with python not working

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I have installed bluetooth with

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez-utils blueman
```

I can find my mobile phone with

```
hcitool scan
```

The problem is when i try to use bluetooth in python file

```
import bluetooth
```

works fine. But when I try

```
nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
```

It's not working. Error is

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'discover_devices'
```

Based on some web pages that should work. 
P.s. basically I would like to send text file to my mobile device programmatically. And this is begining of that proces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. It was very silly mistake. If I could I would delete the question. I have named my other file bluetooth in the same folder. So when I wrote import bluetooth it was my other python file that was imported not bluetooth module.